# Can somebody tell how these graphics where created?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I found the following graphics in the paper *Application of Machine Learning to Bending Processes and Material Identification (Cruz et.al)*.

**Does somebody know how these were made? Is it Tikz?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would bet on [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: Actually, I don't think that these plots are generated using Ti*k*Z or PGFPlots, because the font inside the plots is Arial, Times or Cambria and different fonts are used for the same plot. The axis descriptions are in Computer Modern, however. So probably these plots were generated with some other software and then placed inside a LaTeX document where the axis descriptions were added. Of course, only the use of different fonts does not prove anything. It is just a guess. Anyways, I take it that it *would* be possible, to create something similar with PGFPlots.

Comment: If you want a definite answer, ask the author(s) of the paper :)